# Assign group number for each row, based on columns value ranges

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by, grouping

I have some data, that needs to be clustered into groups. That should be done by a few predefined conditions.

Suppose we have the following table:

```
d = {'ID': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
     'col_1': [12, 3, 7, 13, 19, 25],
     'col_2': [3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4]
    }


df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()
```

[image]

Here, I want to group `ID` based on the following ranges, conditions, on `col_1` and `col_2`.

For `col_1` I divide values into following groups: `[0, 10]`, `[11, 15]`, `[16, 20]`, `[20, +inf]`

For `col_2` just use the `df['col_2'].unique()` values: `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, `[4]`.

The desired grouping is in `group_num` column:

[image]

*notice, that `0` and `3` rows have the same group number and the order, in which group number is assigned*.

For now, I only came up with `if-elif` function to pre-define all the groups. It's not the solution for now cause in my real task there are far more ranges and confitions.

My code snippet, if it's relevant:

```
# This logic is not working cause here I have to predefine all the groups configurations, aka numbers,
# but I want to make groups "dymanicly":
# first group created and if the next row is not in that group -> create new one 

def grouping(val_1, val_2):
    
    # not using match case here, cause my Python < 3.10
    if ((val_1 >= 0) and (val_1 <10)) and (val_2 == 1):
        return 1
    elif ((val_1 >= 0) and (val_1 <10)) and (val_2 == 2):
        return 2
    elif ...
    
    ...

df['group_num'] = df.apply(lambda x: grouping(x.col_1, x.col_2), axis=1)
```

Comment: how `0` row's `group_num` is 3? what is logic of group_num?

Comment: @PandaKim  `0` and `3` row have the same `group_num` because they: 1) both not in first two 2) have `col_1` values in the same range 3) have the same `col_2` value.
The `0` row is assigned to `3` and not to `1` just because of `col_1` ranges. Sure, it can be `1`, but the logic for assigning is the same. I get that `lambda` will not assign 3 in that case.

Comment: 1) both not in first two? what mean? 3) have the same col_2 value? it looks 3 and 2. And can't you explain the logic why row0 is 3?

Comment: @PandaKim
1) both not in first two groups. For row `1` and `2` there already assigned in `group_num` values `1` and `2`. So we use `3` for row `0`.
3) made corrections, was a typo. Now rows `0` and `3` are in the same group, because of `col_1` range and same `col_ 2` value

Comment: ok finally i understand your logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make dataframe for chking group

```
bins = [0, 10, 15, 20, float('inf')]
df1 = df[['col_1', 'col_2']].assign(col_1=pd.cut(df['col_1'], bins=bins, right=False)).sort_values(['col_1', 'col_2'])
```

`df1`

```
    col_1           col_2
1   [0.0, 10.0)     1
2   [0.0, 10.0)     3
0   [10.0, 15.0)    3
3   [10.0, 15.0)    3
4   [15.0, 20.0)    2
5   [20.0, inf)     4
```

chk group by `df1`

```
df1.ne(df1.shift(1)).any(axis=1).cumsum()
```

output:

```
1    1
2    2
0    3
3    3
4    4
5    5
dtype: int32
```

make output to `group_num` column

```
df.assign(group_num=df1.ne(df1.shift(1)).any(axis=1).cumsum())
```

result:

```
    ID  col_1   col_2   group_num
0   100 12      3       3
1   101 3       1       1
2   102 7       3       2
3   103 13      3       3
4   104 19      2       4
5   105 25      4       5
```

Comment: what is `df_chk`?

Comment: after testing, i change name df_chk to df1. but remain 1. sorry.  edit my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the full logic, can't you use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [0, 10, 15, 20, np.inf]
df['group_num'] = pd.cut(df['col_1'], bins=bins,
                         labels=range(1, len(bins)))
```

Output:

```
    ID  col_1  col_2 group_num
0  100     12      3         2
1  101      3      1         1
2  102      7      3         1
3  103     13      2         2
4  104     19      3         3
5  105     25      4         4
```

Comment: Well, that's pretty neat! Will it work on several bins lists and several corresponding columns? Cause in this case for rows 1 and 2 there's the same number and it should be different because of col_2 values

Comment: I think that's a relative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46473375/9137206